# Oracle SQL Query invalid identifier (ORA-00904)

Tags: sql, oracle

I was making an SQL query but got a problem.

This is the query.

```sql
SELECT Count(*) CNT
FROM   job_intern_manage T1
       LEFT JOIN job_intern_detail T2
              ON T1.jid_seq = T2.jid_seq
WHERE  T2.js_seq = '2'
       AND T1.del_yn = 'N'
       AND (SELECT Count(*)
            FROM   (SELECT prof_name
                    FROM   job_intern_report
                    WHERE  jim_seq = T1.jim_seq)
            WHERE  prof_name LIKE '%취업%') >= 1;
```

This is the result.

```
ORA-00904: "T1"."JIM_SEQ": 부적합한 식별자
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
27행, 38열에서 오류 발생
```

I don't know why "T1" is invalid in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this select statement:

```
SELECT Count(*) CNT
FROM   job_intern_manage T1
       LEFT JOIN job_intern_detail T2 ON T1.jid_seq = T2.jid_seq
WHERE  T2.js_seq = '2'
       AND T1.del_yn = 'N'
       AND (SELECT Count(*)
            FROM  job_intern_report
            WHERE jim_seq = T1.jim_seq
              AND prof_name LIKE '%취업%') >= 1;
```

You should check if the job_intern_manage table really has a column named jim_seq.

Comment: I was fool. Thank you so much to your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT Count(*) as CNT
FROM job_intern_manage jim JOIN
     job_intern_detail jid
     ON jim.jid_seq = jid.jid_seq
WHERE jid.js_seq = '2' AND
      jim.del_yn = 'N' AND
      EIXSTS (SELECT 1
              FROM job_intern_report jir
              WHERE jir.jim_seq = jim.jim_seq AND
                    jir.prof_name LIKE '%취업%'
             );
```

The problem with your query is that the correlation clause is nested two levels -- and Oracle does not allow that.

However, note the additional fixes:

- The `WHERE` clause turns the `JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  So there is no reason to specify a `LEFT JOIN`.
- The tables are given *meaningful* table aliases (abbreviations) rather than meaningless aliases such as `t1` and `t2`.  This makes a query much easier to write and to read.
- All columns are qualified, so it is clear what table they refer to.  This is particularly recommended with correlated subqueries.
- `EXISTS` is more efficient than aggregation for what you want to do.

Comment: wow!! Are you teacher? Your explain is gorgeous!! Thank you :)